# Double.Parse("string") FormatException with correct input

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse

```
Double.Parse(rowData[j++]).
```

The input sting is correct ("7,412"), j=123 so it worked until this point. All numbers are written with ",".

Even more if I type `Double.Parse(rowData[j])` in watch it works.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What happens if you type `Double.Parse(rowData[j+1])` in watch?

Comment: Probably it's because of decimal comma, while you need point according to localization.

Comment: If you type `Double.Parse(rowData[j])` *after* `j++`, you're getting a different value.

Comment: @hvd you are correct it seems not all fields have data and j++ shows me only the next entry

Comment: Executing `Double.Parse(rowData[j++])` is same as if you were executing `Double.Parse(rowData[j]); j=j+1;`

Comment: Each time you watch `Double.Parse(rowData[j++])` in debug window, you increase the `j` value so it's evaluating different things every time.

Comment: there's one cell with incorrect value, split expression into two `Double.Parse(rowData[j]); j=j+1;` and see what exact `j` you get during crash. `Double.Parse(rowData[j++])` can be confusing, saying that `j` is `123` when it crashed, where as it crashed for `j==122`

Answer (score 0):

You have comma instead of your decimal separator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw

You should use `AllowThousands` `NumberType` if that's thousands separator

```
NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.Float;
Double.Parse(value, styles);
```

Or you should replace your comma with `.` using `string.Replace` prior to parsing if that's considered decimal separator

Comment: If this were the problem, `Double.Parse(rowData[j])` wouldn't work in the Watch window, but the OP has already stated that does work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can try:

```
value = "4,320.64";
styles = NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
            NumberStyles.Float; 
number = Double.Parse(value, styles);
```